# Yii2 error strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: yii2

I made a query like this:

```
return Orders::find()->where([
    'customer_id' => $CustomerID,
    ['in', 'order_status', $statuses]
])->all();
```

It returns the following error:

> "message": "strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",

Answer (score 0):

This return a  collection of Orders Rows

```
return Orders::find()
     ->where(['customer_id' => $CustomerID,['in','order_status',$statuses]])->all();
```

The strtouppoer work on a string so If you want a column value you should get a rows  and a column  eg: try using

```
  $myOrders  =  Orders::find()
    ->where(['customer_id' => $CustomerID,['in','order_status',$statuses]])->all();
  return $myOrder[0]->my_column_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had code like this so i got error,  in Yii2, mongodb
"strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string"

```
    [
    '$match' => [
                  [
                    '$or' => [
                    ['patient.appointment_info.lab.lab_number' => $lab_number],
                            ['test.name' => ['$regex' => ".*$searchText.*"]],
                            ['patient.name' => ['$regex' => ".*$searchText.*"]],
                            ['user.full_name' => ['$regex' => ".*$searchText.*"]],
                        ]
            ]
        ]
        ],
```

it is fixed like

```
[
            '$match' => [
                        '$or' => [
                            ['patient.appointment_info.lab.lab_number' => $lab_number],
                            ['test.name' => ['$regex' => ".*$searchText.*"]],
                            ['patient.name' => ['$regex' => ".*$searchText.*"]],
                            ['user.full_name' => ['$regex' => ".*$searchText.*"]],
                        ]
            ]
        ],
```

I was using one extra curly brace.